# Does an "Any CPU" / "MSIL" edition of filtdump.exe exist?

Tags: c#, dll, compilation, 32bit-64bit

I'm aiming to achieve "no warnings / no errors" for compiling a C# project that makes use of "filtdump.exe", the copy given to me is likely only 64-bit. Is there a 32+64 bit edition of "filtdump.exe" that could be dropped in to get this warning message to go away?

If so, where is it found? How could I download a copy?

My research so far kind of gave me a few odd leads such as:

- [Microsoft says it's no longer supported](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms692535(v=vs.85).aspx)?
- [It's a part of the Windows SDK](https://thesqldude.com/tag/filtdump/)?
- Which ones (ie: only Windows 6.1 [Windows 7], or all editions after that)
- Which sub-package(s), if any checkboxes are needed?

> There was a mismatch between the processor architecture of the project being built "MSIL" and the processor architecture of the reference "filtdump, Version=2.0.27.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=4a949968764df20e, processorArchitecture=AMD64", "AMD64". This mismatch may cause runtime failures. Please consider changing the targeted processor architecture of your project through the Configuration Manager so as to align the processor architectures between your project and references, or take a dependency on references with a processor architecture that matches the targeted processor architecture of your project.

Comment: It is just an innocent warning produced by the assembly linker.  It predicts a possible problem once you deploy your app to a machine with a 32-bit operating system.  Well, that will certainly be the case when you deploy that copy of filtdump.exe as well.  Maybe you can take care of it and ensure the machine has a 32-bit copy of filtdump.exe.  But you'll certainly first have to make sure it is an old machine.  You were warned, that's all.  And no, there is no option to suppress it.  Just copy the 32-bit version off the machine on which you are going to test your program.

Comment: This is a rather suspect question. `filtdump` was a development tool, and not redistributable AFAIK. You used it to develop `IFilter` extensions, which were used up to Windows XP. How does `filtdump` end up in your assembly manifest?

Comment: It is a COM server.  Which, come to think of it, offers a workaround.  Run tlbimp.exe to generate the interop library and add a reference to that one instead.

Comment: It's a rather suspicious project that I simply inherited. You know how that goes. I can't imagine what they were thinking when they hacked together their solution. Just trying to clean up the mess.